# Best way in the django templates to highlight active nav link based on path

Tags: django, django-templates

When a navigation link is clicked and page is redirected to that link, I am trying to highlight the active link in the nav bar. I was able to achieve the highlighting by using if and else. But I would like to know is there any way better than this. Right now I have to duplicate this code again and again.

```html
   <li class="nav-item">
                <a 
                {% if request.path == '/register' %} 
                    class="active nav-link" 
                {% else %} 
                    class="nav-link" 
                {% endif %} 
                href=" {% url 'register' %} ">
                    Register 
                </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set the nav item URL as a variable, you can use it for the `href` and a check to see if it's the current page.

```
{% url 'about' as url %}
<li class="nav-item {% if request.path == url %}active{% endif %}">
  <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url }}">About</a>
</li>
```